# Proof by contradiction to this inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, proof-writing

Prove, by contradiction, that if $w$, $z$ $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|w|$ $\leq 1$ and

$$w^{n} z + w^{n - 1} z^2 + \cdots+ wz^n = 1$$
 then $|z|$ $\gt$ $\frac{1}{2}$

I have been thinking about this problem since a very long time. Going through the text again and again but still have no clue about how to prove this. Once I thought of using Weierstrass inequality but I doubt it's validity here.

Nothing coming to mind.

What method can I apply to come to the conclusion here?

Answer (score 3):

If $|z|\le\frac12$, then
$$
1=|w^{n} z + w^{n - 1} z^2 + \cdots+ wz^n|\le \frac12+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}<1.
$$
So you reach a contradition.

Comment: Didn't understand it. Can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: Sure, what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: I also kinda didn't understand what you just did here. Kindly write a bit detailed answer.

Comment: I can only add that $1<1$ is false. Unless you detail what you don't understand, nothing else can be added.

Comment: He is using the triangle inequality.

Comment: How did you use this $z \leq \frac12$ and what you did further using this?

Comment: Did you took $w = 1$?

Comment: He is using the fact that $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}=1$. +$1$